# How to plot predicted value for poisson GLMM

Tags: r

I have fit a model using glmer from the lme4 package.I used the following code to fit the model.

```
  GLMmmia.4<- glmer(Total_abun ~
                      EC+ DO_sat  + TP+   
                        Vegetationcover  +(1 | Season), data=wetlandmacro , family=poisson,  control=lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e4)))

> summary(GLMmmia.4)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
  Approximation) [glmerMod]
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: 
Total_abun ~ EC + DO_sat + TP + Vegetationcover + (1 | Season)
   Data: wetlandmacro
Control: 
lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 20000))

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  4817.3   4833.1  -2402.6   4805.3       98 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-9.8730 -4.4156 -0.4338  3.1763 19.4737 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Season (Intercept) 0.009201 0.09592 
Number of obs: 104, groups:  Season, 2

Fixed effects:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      5.0118238  0.0931197   53.82  < 2e-16 ***
EC              -0.0011036  0.0001632   -6.76 1.34e-11 ***
DO_sat          -0.0009736  0.0003168   -3.07  0.00211 ** 
TP               0.2050763  0.0422935    4.85 1.24e-06 ***
Vegetationcover -0.0015678  0.0005251   -2.99  0.00283 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) EC     DO_sat TP    
EC          -0.392                     
DO_sat      -0.521  0.313              
TP          -0.021  0.155 -0.167       
Vegetatncvr -0.617  0.293  0.606 -0.142
```

I appreciate any help to plot predicted value of response variable (species abundance) as a function of each fixed effect (environmental variables)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plot` and `fitted` separately for each one of your fixed effects. For exemple: 
`plot(fitted(GLMmmia.4)~EC)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I got  Error in (function (formula, data = NULL, subset = NULL, na.action = na.fail,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'EC')

Comment: I suppose you have missing values in one or more of your fixed effects. If that's so, you'll have different lengths of fitted and fixed effect (EC in the exemple) values and a the plot will not work. I think you should add a 'na.action=na.exclude' to your model. The function will insert NAs in the predicted values, but I am note sure about the machanics of the function in that case.